# Aligning images with the depth map in Opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, alignment

I am working on a dataset where we have `RGB` images and corresponding `depth` maps. The depth maps aren't aligned perfectly with the `RGB` images and we are given the `Sensor Calibration` for aligning. Here are the params:

```
intrinsic matrix for the depth sensor
584.27 0 337.11
0 584.27 254.17
0 0 1

intrinsic matrix of the color camera
519.47 0 329.76
0 519.47 264.09
0 0 1

extrinsic parameters mapping the depth coordinate system to the camera coordinate system
rotation matrix 
0.999947 -0.00432361 0.00929419 
0.00446314 0.999877 0.0150443 
-0.009228 -0.015085 0.999844 

translation vector
25.0198  -0.2000  3.2308
```

How can I use these to align the depth maps with the RGB images in OpenCV python?

Comment: check [this method](https://www.codefull.net/2016/03/align-depth-and-color-frames-depth-and-rgb-registration/)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, here what I've done in Python (where K is intrinsic for depth sensor and color cameras, and ext the extrinsic):

```
# All what we need to align our images:

depth_scale = 0.001

fx_d = K_depth[0,0]
fy_d = K_depth[1,1]
cx_d = K_depth[0,2]
cy_d = K_depth[1,2]

fx_rgb = K_col[0,0]
fy_rgb = K_col[1,1]
cx_rgb = K_col[0,2]
cy_rgb = K_col[1,2]

height = depth.shape[0]
width = depth.shape[1]

aligned = np.zeros((height,width,6))

for v in range (height):
    for u in range (width):
        # Apply Depth intrinsics
        z = depth[v,u].sum() * depth_scale
        x = ((u - cx_d) * z) / fx_d
        y = ((v - cy_d) * z) / fy_d
        
        # Apply extrinsic
        transformed = np.dot(ext ,np.array([x,y,z,1])).T
        aligned[v,u,0] = transformed[0]
        aligned[v,u,1] = transformed[1]
        aligned[v,u,2] = transformed[2]
        
for v in range (height):
    for u in range (width):
        # Apply RGB intrinsic
        x = (aligned[v,u,0] * fx_rgb / aligned[v,u,2]) + cx_rgb
        y = (aligned[v,u,1] * fy_rgb / aligned[v,u,2]) + cy_rgb
        
        # Endle out of bound pixels
        if x > width-1 or y > height-1 or x < 0 or y < 0:
            pass
        
        else:
            x = int(round(x))
            y = int(round(y))
        
            aligned[v,u,3] = color[y, x, 0]
            aligned[v,u,4] = color[y, x, 1]
            aligned[v,u,5] = color[y, x, 2]
            
# Retrive RGB value from our aligned version
test = np.zeros((height,width,3))
for i in range (height):
    for j in range (width):
        test[i,j] = aligned[i,j][3:6]
plt.imshow(test.astype(int))
```

Comment: Good code but implementation can be better w.r.t. Python. It helped me confirm my thoughts as I was trying to solve the problem with the reverse perspective. Was able to get my code up. THANKS :)